# sql syntax error with mysql select using inet_ntoa

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have an ip stored in the database as an unsigned int but when i try and run this select i get a syntax error. i have tried both versions below.

```
SELECT `id`, INET_NTOA(`from`) AS from, INET_NTOA(`to`) AS to, `campaignid`  FROM `customiplist` WHERE `campaignid` = 1

SELECT id, INET_NTOA(from) AS from, INET_NTOA(to) AS to, campaignid  FROM customiplist WHERE campaignid = 1

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, INET_NTOA(`to`) AS to, `campaignid` FROM `customiplist` WHERE `campa' at line 1
```

i feel like i'm going mad because all the column names and table name is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FROM` and `TO` are [reserved keywords in MySQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)L. If you're going to use them, you *must* wrap them in ticks:

```
SELECT `id`, INET_NTOA(`from`) AS `from`, INET_NTOA(`to`) AS `to`, `campaignid`  FROM `customipblocklist` WHERE `campaignid` = 1
```

Honestly, those are bad choices for column names. I recommend changing them if at all possible.

Comment: Shouldn't the `to` in `AS to` also be backticked? Since `to` is also a reserved word.

Comment: your right.... i cant believe i missed that. thank you for the help. all works as expected now. your right i will change that column name.

Comment: Two for the price of one; what a bargain ;-)

Comment: Believe it or not, there's another question that just popped up doing almost the same mistake; *double baffle*

Comment: It's deja vu all over again

Comment: i was sure it had something to do with INET_NTOA ... palm to forehead moment.. :(

Comment: Déjà vue's the word(s)